# Content-Disposition Considered Harmful?

Tags: wcf, content-disposition

I am currently working on a WCF service that returns a file based on a HTTP GET request. The main concept of the service goes like this:

```
public Stream MyGetMethod()
{
    // Fetch the file
    byte[] myFile = FetchMyFile();

    // Set the name of the file using Content-Disposition
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse
       .Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyFile");

    // Return the file
    return new MemoryStream(myFile);
}
```

I use the `Content-Disposition` header to tell the browser that it should name the file `MyFile` and that it should show a SaveAs dialog (the `attachment` part).

While this works, I have been reading some bad things about `Content-Disposition`.

*[RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.5) states:*

> RFC 1806 [35], from which the often implemented Content-Disposition (see section 19.5.1) header in HTTP is derived, has a number of very serious security considerations. *Content-Disposition is not part of the HTTP standard*, but since it is widely implemented, we are documenting its use and risks for implementors. See RFC 2183 [49] (which updates RFC 1806) for details.

*And from [RFC2183](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) I get:*

> Since this memo provides a way for the sender to suggest a filename,
>   a receiving MUA must take care that the sender's suggested filename
>   does not represent a hazard. Using UNIX as an example, some hazards
>   would be:
>
> - Creating startup files (e.g., ".login").
> - Creating or overwriting system files (e.g., "/etc/passwd").
> - Overwriting any existing file.
> - Placing executable files into any command search path
>         (e.g., "~/bin/more").
> - Sending the file to a pipe (e.g., "| sh").
>
>   In general, the receiving MUA should not name or place the file
>     such    that it will get interpreted or executed without the user
>     explicitly    initiating the action.

I see there are some serious security aspects in this, but I am not quite sure if this should stop me from using it, like in the WCF service above?

As I see it, I think it should be alright since all the major browsers understand the header, and while the code in the snippet above is that simple, I cannot see how that can ever be a security threat? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: A more recent document on Content-Disposition is RFC 6266.

Answer (score 0):

Its safe to use `Content-Disposition`, for additional safety, don't allow user to give file-names, or do add some random unique name prefix or sufix or file extension yourself.

Comment: Adding a file extension isn't needed as long as the proper mime type is passed (which the browsers use to build the file extension).

Comment: i said `OR file extension`.